# How to insert EMPName based on EmpID that was select in dropdown,the remainin valuse can be insert in Orders table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How to insert EMPName based on EmpID that was select in dropdown,the remainin valuse can be insert in Orders table?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5656.jpg)

Example:

```
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into  orders (OrderID,ShipName,ShipCity) values("+TextBox1.Text+","+TextBox3.Text+","+TextBox2.Text+")", con);
```

how to write query for getting EMPName that was select in EMPId Drop Down and

Answer (score 0):

You could do the same thing you're already doing, only instead of passing a specified list of parameters into your query, use a `SELECT` that accepts those same parameters as part of the value list to be returned, i.e.:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("
INSERT INTO Orders 
(
  [OrderID]
 ,[EmpName]
 ,[OrderDate]
 ,[ShipName]
 ,[ShipCity]
 ,[EmpCity]
)
SELECT 
  " + TextBox1.Text + " AS OrderID
 ,E.[Name] AS [EmpName]
 ,<Some Date> AS [OrderDate] --Wasn't included in your post
 ," + TextBox3.Text + " AS [ShipName]
 ," + TextBox2.Text + " AS [ShipCity]
 ,E.[City] AS [EmpCity]
FROM [Employee] E
WHERE E.[RowID] = " + <DropDownMenu.Text> + ";"
, con);
```

On the other hand, if you just want to select the employee's name based on the ID chosen from the Dropdown Menu, you could always just run a separate query:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("
SELECT E.[Name]
FROM [Employee] E
WHERE E.[RowID] = " + <DropDownMenu.Text> + ";" , con);
```

Please note that instances such as this are vulnerable to SQL-Injection, so you're going to want to make sure that you're checking the parameters passed into the query for those kinds of attempts.